# How to test whether an element is clickable in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, stenciljs

How can one determine whether a particular element registers a click? It's considered non-clickable when the node is, e.g., `disabled`, has `pointer-events: none`, etc.

Basically, the question is how to mimic [`isClickable` of WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isClickable/).

Answer (score 2):

**isClickable**

as defined in the [WebDriverIO API Docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isClickable/):

> Return true if the selected DOM-element:
>
> 1. exists
> 2. is visible
> 3. is within viewport (if not try scroll to it)
> 4. its center is not overlapped with another element
> 5. is not disabled
>
> otherwise return false.

**Exists**

```
const selector = 'span.selector'
const exists = await page.$(selector) !== null
```

**Is Visible**

```
const selector = 'span.selector'
const element = await page.$(selector)
const visible1 = await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true})
const visible2 = await element.isVisible()
```

**Is Within Viewport**

```
const selector = 'span.selector'
const element = await page.$(selector)
const insideViewport = element.isIntersectingViewport()
```

**It's Center isn't Overlapped with Another Element**

```
const selector = 'span.selector'
const isNotOverlapped = await page.$eval(selector, (element) => {
    const boundingBox = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    const centerPoint = {
        x: (boundingBox.left + boundingBox.right)/2,
        y: (boundingBox.top + boundingBox.bottom)/2
    }
    const topElement = document.elementFromPoint(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y)
    return element.isSameNode(topElement) || element.contains(topElement)
})
```

**Is Not Disabled**

```
const selector = 'span.selector'
const isNotDisabled = await page.$eval(selector, (element) => {
    return element.getAttribute('disabled') === null
})
```

To check all of them are **TRUE** then:

```
const isClickable = async function (selector) {

    const element = await page.$(selector)
    const exists = await page.$(selector) !== null
    const visible = await element.isVisible()
    const insideViewport = element.isIntersectingViewport()
    const isNotOverlapped = await page.$eval(selector, (element) => {
        const boundingBox = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    const centerPoint = {
        x: (boundingBox.left + boundingBox.right)/2,
        y: (boundingBox.top + boundingBox.bottom)/2
    }
    const topElement = document.elementFromPoint(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y)
        return element.isSameNode(topElement) || element.contains(topElement)
    })
    const isNotDisabled = await page.$eval(selector, (element) => {
        return element.getAttribute('disabled') === null
    })

    return exists && visible && insideViewport && isNotOverlapped && isNotDisabled
}

// To call this method, simply put:

await isClickable('.some > .selectors')
```